# Finding the number of occurrences for a specific value

Tags: sql, filemaker

I've been working on some sql code in FileMaker and I have a basically a table called "Incidents" and a field called "Incident Type" under the said table. I use the code below to count the number of times the option "Injury" is selected from the field "Incident Type". This works 100%. However, I have been trying to sort the records in this database by the year it happened and to no surprise the code is counting all times the option "Injury" is selected in its respective field. I want to only count the times when the field "Incident Type" is equal to "Injury" and the other field "Incident Year" is equal to '2014'. Can someone revise the code below to show that?

```
ExecuteSQL(

"SELECT Count(\"Incident Type\")

FROM \"Incidents\"

WHERE \"Incident Type\" = ?"

;"";"";"Injury")
```

Comment: You need to rephrase your question as it is not clear what are you trying to do. Are you trying to display a total number of injuries for 2014 or are you trying to select a number of injuries  grouped and sorted by year?  Paul Rowe answer below covers the first case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work for you, but it should be close enough for you to tweak to your needs.

```
ExecuteSQL(
  "
    SELECT Count(\"Incident Type\")
    FROM \"Incidents\"
    WHERE (\"Incident Type\" = ?)
      AND (\"Incident Year\" = ?)
  "; ""; ""; "Injury"; "2014"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to display total injuries for a number of years, sorted by year

```
ExecuteSQL(
  "
    SELECT \"Incident Year\", Count(\"Incident Type\")
    FROM \"Incidents\"
    WHERE (\"Incident Type\" = ?)
    GROUP BY \"Incident Year\"
    ORDER BY 1
  "; ""; ""; "Injury"
)
```